# angular resolve function depends on other resolver

Tags: angular, angular5

In the angular app, even before i load a home page, I would like to get a data from backed. but even before i get the data from backend, I need to send the country name the user with.

so, now data call is depends on first resolver call. In this case how to handle?

here is my code :

```
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home/home.component';
import { ResolveService } from '../shared/service/resolve.service';
import { ResolveCountryService } from '../shared/service/resolve-country.service';

export const AppRoutes:Routes = [

    {path:"", component: HomeComponent, resolve:{ country : ResolveCountryService, data:ResolveService} }

]
```

here `ResolveCountryService` has to share the country name to `ResolveService` so what is the correct approach to manage this?

**UPDATE**

If I do like this:

```
export const AppRoutes:Routes = [

    {path:"", component: HomeComponent, resolve:{ country : ResolveCountryService, resolve : {data:ResolveService } } }

]
```

I am getting an error as :

```
src/app/shared/service/resolve-country.service"' has no exported member 'ResolveCountryService'.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? The question is not clear.

Comment: You could create a service which is responsible for retrieving and storing the country of the user. Simply add this service as a dependency for your data service (similar, like you  would do with any other service by declaring it in the constructor). Like this you can check if the country is available and if not resolve the country first, then resolve the data.

Comment: @ManelAlonso - I require to get the data from serve by country wise. so I need to find the user country and the country name has to go for get the data from backed, when both done now the page can load. if require more info let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`async` and `await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) as shown in [this plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/bx8eGvIFWhqdzCqpB7fb/)

For example, you'll have an `async` method that will return a promise with desired result (it will be the first call you want to wait before doing anything else).

Then you can call it in an other `async` method and `await` it. 
(you can await it in a `try/catch` if you want).

In your case, `ResolveCountryService` will await the method that retrieve the user's country.

Be careful: `await` only works with promises, but you can resolve an observable in the `async` method that returns the promise to `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a flatMap

```
export class YourDataResolver implements Resolve<object> {
     constructor(private dataService: DataService, private countryService: CountryService) { }

      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<YourDataType> {

           return this.countryService.getCountry().flatMap( country=> 
               return this.dataService.findByCountry(country)
          ));
       }
}
```